# Are Session variables present in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm trying to store a value gobally in my custom module.I'm making it as Gobal variable.But in form the gobal variable is not at all good.I want to store that variable in session. Can any one please tell me how to access Session variables in Openerp.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What information are you trying to store, and why?

Answer (score 3):

In OpenERP you are use **`UID`**. this UID is define the current user session. For every time HTTP page routing **`_authenticate()`** method call.

This **`_authenticate()`** method is implemented in this path.

> **OpenERP/server/trunk/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py**

#### Authenticate get using UID

```
def _authenticate(self, auth_method='user'):
    if request.session.uid:
        try:
            request.session.check_security()
            # what if error in security.check()
            #   -> res_users.check()
            #   -> res_users.check_credentials()
        except (openerp.exceptions.AccessDenied, openerp.http.SessionExpiredException):
            # All other exceptions mean undetermined status (e.g. connection pool full),
            # let them bubble up
            request.session.logout()
    getattr(self, "_auth_method_%s" % auth_method)()
    return auth_method
```

Comment: How can I inherit this _authenticate method in my custom module?

Answer (score 0):

The solution may depend on why you need a global variable. But probably what you need is to use `context`:

A method can set a key/value in the current `context` and it will be passed along and made available to further methods. (The rule is for methods always pass along the context to other methods called by them).

Comment: I'm customing the Sales Module.When i'm trying to create a Sale Order i need to give a **OrderValue** and based on that value i need to change the amount in the Sales Order Line.So i need to store the **OrderValue** as global to do my calculation.

Comment: So, OrderValue is a field of the Sales Order, therefore is data available when handling a Sales Order instance.